# Not able to link the xamarin forms custom control in the content page

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm not able to link the xamarin forms custom control in the content page.

Have created the following xamarin custom control "AlertMessage",

```
public class AlertMessage:ContentView
{
    private Frame _frame;
    private Grid _alertGrid;
    private StackLayout _alertLayout, _alertLayoutContent;
    private BoxView _alertBoxView;
    private Label _alertMessage;

    public static readonly BindableProperty TitleProperty = BindableProperty.Create("Title", typeof(string), typeof(AlertMessage), default(string));

    public string Title
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TitleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TitleProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty = BindableProperty.Create("Text", typeof(string), typeof(AlertMessage), default(string));

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    public AlertMessage()
    {
        InitLayout();
    }

    public void InitLayout()
    {
        _alertGrid = new Grid { Padding = 0 };

        _alertGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition
        {
            Height = GridLength.Star
        });

        _alertGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = 8 });
        _alertGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = GridLength.Star });

        _alertLayout = new StackLayout
        {
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            BackgroundColor = Constants.MMSGAlertBackgroundColor,
            Padding = 0
        };

        _alertBoxView = new BoxView
        {
            Color = Constants.MMSGAlertTextColor,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
        };

        _alertLayout.Children.Add(_alertBoxView);

        _alertLayoutContent = new StackLayout
        {
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            Padding = 16
        };

        _alertMessage = new Label
        {
            Text = Text,
            TextColor = Constants.MMSGAlertTextColor
        };

        _alertLayoutContent.Children.Add(_alertMessage);

        _alertGrid.Children.Add(_alertLayout, 0, 0);
        _alertGrid.Children.Add(_alertLayoutContent, 1, 0);

        _frame = new Frame
        {
            OutlineColor = Constants.MMSGAlertBorderColor,
            BackgroundColor = Constants.MMSGAlertBackgroundColor,
            Padding = new Thickness(2, 2, 0, 2),
            HasShadow = false,
            Content = _alertGrid,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
        };

        this.Content = _frame;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to render this custom control in the content page using the c# code,

```
var alertMessage = new AlertMessage
            {
                Text = ViewModel.AlertReviewMessage,
                Title = "Please review"
            };
```

I'm getting the following build error, on rendering this custom control in the content page.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Can't resolve the reference 'APP.Mobile.CustomControls.AlertText', referenced from the method 'System.Object APP.Mobile.StatusSummaryContentPage::<GetDataTemplate>b__7_0()' in 'MMSG.Mobile, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.   RemServ.Mobile.iOS
```

Please let me know what link am i missing here to add a custom control to a content page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your content view is missing `InitializeComponent();` in the constructor.It should be like below

```
public AlertView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Content.BindingContext = this;
}
```

I hope you have added reference to the shared project from custom controls project. `using APP.Mobile.CustomControls;`

Also you should add `[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]` on top of the class declaration.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have added the reference of my customcontrol class in the content page. But still the same error. Also, to which class the attribute, [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)] should be added? Is it for the custom control or the content page class

Comment: The parameters, Text and Title are not getting passed to the custom control. Could you please let me know what is causing this.

Comment: Solved ? I had same issue , use `Content.BindingContext = this;` in custom control constructor

Comment: Yes Prateek. Thank you

Comment: Could you also please help me with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52742555/xamarin-forms-content-is-not-getting-vertically-center-aligned-in-the-stacklay