# Xamarin Forms - Content is not getting vertically center aligned in the stackLayout

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm trying to create a custom control in Xamarin forms to show the alert message.

On few scenarios the content is getting vertically aligned middle but on few cases it is overflowing the frame.

Could you please let me know what changes I need to make to have the content always vertically middle and size of the content expands.

```
        _alertLayout = new StackLayout
        {
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
        };

        _alertLayoutHighlighter = new StackLayout
        {
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            BackgroundColor = Constants.MMSGAlertBackgroundColor,
            Padding = 0,
            WidthRequest = 8
        };

        _alertBoxView = new BoxView
        {
            Color = Constants.MMSGAlertTextColor,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
        };

        _alertLayoutHighlighter.Children.Add(_alertBoxView);

        _alertLayoutContent = new StackLayout
        {
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            Padding = new Thickness(16)
        };

        _alertMessage = new Label
        {
            TextColor = Constants.MMSGAlertTextColor,
            FontSize = 12
        };

        _alertLayoutContent.Children.Add(_alertMessage);

        _alertLayout.Children.Add(_alertLayoutHighlighter);
        _alertLayout.Children.Add(_alertLayoutContent);

        _frame = new Frame
        {
            OutlineColor = Constants.MMSGAlertBorderColor,
            BackgroundColor = Constants.MMSGAlertBackgroundColor,
            Padding = new Thickness(2, 2, 0, 2),
            HasShadow = false,
            Content = _alertLayout,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
        };

        this.Content = _frame;
```

[image]

Comment: the red one is Custom control AlertView? screenshot doesnt show its not vertically center aligned. I notice you havent set `VerticalOptions = "Center"` or `"CenterAndExpand"` anywhere. I think you have to do it in the page where it calls the AlertView

Comment: Then use VerticalTextAlignment of the Label to Center! Or use VerticalOptions of that Label to Center.

Answer (score 0):

You should adjust the vertical options of your label, either to Center, or to CenterAndExpand:

```
 _alertMessage = new Label
        {
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            TextColor = Constants.MMSGAlertTextColor,
            FontSize = 12
        };
```